# Bootstrap collapsible card moving parent card border

Tags: bootstrap-4, border

I've got a bootstrap collapse button but when the card shows it changes the size of its parent card's border. How do I prevent this from happening? I'd like the card to overlap its parent card

Comment: Could you add the code you have now for reference?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting these two new divs and the styles. Now when the card is displayed no other elements of the page move.

`

my code  
`

...Woops looks like Stack Overflow won't let me put my code as an example. sorry everyone. In short though the first div had a style called position:relative
and the second one had a style of position:absolute; z-index: 1000